# Data transferring issue from wifi connected glasses when mobile data is also active

Tags: android, networking, stream, camera, wifi

The problem is this. You need to connect a WiFi camera to your phone and restream to red5pro. I am using this code to connect to internet.

```
val connectivityManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)

val networkRequest = builder.build()
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback())
connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
        networkRequest,
        object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
            }
        }
```

In this case, a problem occurs, the Internet is active, but I do not receive images from the camera. And without this code, on the contrary, I get an image, but I don't have internet.
When using Speedify everything works and I get an image and I have internet.
My question is, is it possible to get the same without using speedify, if so, how?

I tried using Speedify but i need an option to avoid using Speedify